# How can I see the window decoration icon in my Plasma 5 panel?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, icons, panel, plasma-5

On Kubuntu 15.10, Chrome apps always show with the Chrome icon in the panel, even if their window decoration has a different icon. Changing the launcher icon also does not change the panel icon, as shown:

[image: picture showing a calculator icon on the launcher, a 2048 icon on the window decoration, and a Chrome icon on the panel]

Is there a way to show the window decoration icon in the panel? It would improve the native feel of Chrome apps.